# How to import all types from a module in Angular2 / Typescript (and deal with renaming of a module)?

Tags: angular, typescript, module

Each time I need to import a new type, I have to manually add it, which is very cumbersome especially if you are used working with C#, where you don't need to care about filenames, but namespace is enough. It is especially bad when you rename a file and have to rename all of the imports.

E.g. I have this line:

```
import { Headers, Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

So first of all I would like to import all types, something like:

```
import * from '@angular/http'
```

Next step I would like to create files a declarations with imports that will have multiple imports from a `@angular/core`, `@angular/http`, etc. and then include them in my services e.g. In this case I can group some declarations in a "virtual namespace" that I can reference from my files.

Is it possible to achieve or there is some better way that can reduce the pain of manually importing things and dealing with renaming/moving a module? Are there any drawbacks of doing this (I am not sure what importing of a module implies. In C# and such that would be just additional namespaces to look for references during static compilation which you usually don't care about at all)?

P.S. There seems to be some kind of `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'` syntax, but I can't manage to make it work, seems it only works with .d.ts declarations, but I am not quite sure...

Comment: You may ruin tree shaking with this approach. I would suggest to take a look at some decent IDE that can take care of imports for you.

Comment: I use Visual Studio and it apparently cannot do that :( I do understand that tree shaking will be ruined (though don't really know why, it can well go and see further down if the type is used or not, like R# does for C#). Any good suggestions for IDE that supports angular2 and typescript well?

Comment: The problem with tree shaking is not types themselves but exports. Tree shaking is performed by bundling tool (Webpack, Rollup). If it meets `*` import instead of named one, the shaking may suffer. Jetbrains products (Webstorm) are great for TS development - adding new import is just alt+enter. And I guess that VS Code can handle this too.